# API Design - two step resource creation

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I'm developing an API that allows consumers to create a resource. For example, a "user" resource can *somewhat* be created via POST and this payload (trying to use [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/), btw):

```
POST /users HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": {
    "type": "users",
    "attributes": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe"
    }
  }
}
```

I say *somewhat* created because the resource is actually being created on an external system (and my API acts as proxy).

To *completely* create the resource, my API needs to take the second step -- and this step relies on information that my API does not have access to. The API consumer will, at a later point, obtain this additional information (e.g. via an SMS). The API consumer then needs to call my API again with this additional information in order to complete the second step of the resource creation.

**What should this secondary call to my API look like?** It would still be a POST to `/users`, right? Perhaps just replace the `attributes` with the additional information (e.g. `"sms_key": "SHy562NSkd"`)?

```
POST /users HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": {
    "type": "users",
    "attributes": {
      "sms_key": "SHy562NSkd"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the API can completely perform this secondary step without any knowledge of the first step, but the API does have a way to marry the second step with the first step (might be useful for returning results about the resource created).

Comment: I'm afraid we can not say how your API should looks like, among many and good reasons, because you didn't explain what are your goals? Would you like to have a RESTful API? A Json-Rpc API? What is the problem with the actual implentation?

Comment: RESTful. There is no implementation for the second part. I'm trying to get some opinions on the best approach to implement this.

Comment: Ok. One question. Why the json does inform *type*, when the type is explicit in the URI?

Comment: That seems to be the in norm in JSON API.

Comment: @Laiv according the the JSON API spec, "A 'resource identifier object' MUST contain type and id members."

Comment: Yes. I have read it :-). At the writting of the comment, I didn't know what Json API was.

Comment: @Laiv ...that's because it's a poorly positioned opinion paper masquerading as something official. It's a bad idea to stray beyond the traditional standards bodies unless you already understand what those standards bodies say and are seeking alternative recommendations.

Comment: @K.AlanBates I'm afraid I didn't get you. what's a poorly positioned opinion paper? The JSON API specification? There're several models out there trying to win "the race". Do you think that JSON API is poorly implementing HAL?

Comment: @Laiv the publications at `jsonapi.org`. Pretty much all of that is deprecated, but it seems to be a collection of bad practices even for the point in time that it was published (2015)

Comment: I found them to be fair enough:-/. However, I'm not a guru of the HAL. Would you mind sharing some other site with better references or definitions? I'm interested,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me in advance for neglecting a key factor in this question. [API JSON](http://jsonapi.org/) is a specification.

In the first place, JSON API implements [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) which in my opinion, makes easier the answer to the question.

Attending your last comment, I have checked out the official website and, as I expected, JSON API and I are aligned with the solution you need. However, we differ in some points.

#### Step 1: [Creating a new resource](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating)

Let consumers discover the new resource. This is essentially what HATEOAS suggests. If we do, consumers can follow the link and address further operations to the new  URI.

*For brevity, I will leave out the request and the response body*.

Take a look at the example:

**1.1. Request**

```
POST /photos HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/and.api+json
```

**1.2. Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: http://example.com/photos/550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
```

Note that, `/photos` and `/users` are equivalent. Look at the response headers. As I commented in my previous answer, the response *SHOULD* contain the header `Location` which contains the URL to the new resource. This is how we make new resources available after its creation.

Special attention to the specification, which states that, according with the state of the resource on the server-side, we should respond with one or another code.

You might be interested in responses `202 Accepted` if the resource in the remote API (the one you are proxying) is not created at the moment of the request. For example, when the remote resource is created anytime in the future. Check out the 3rd API documentation. It's important for you to know what's the state of the remote resource after the POST request.

**1.3. The identifier**

You have commented that you have a way to marry both steps. It does mean that you have a way to identify the remote resource in the remote API. Fine. You have to make available such mechanisms. Maybe with a deferred id or maybe using the remote resource identifier. Whatever you choose, you make it available to the rest through the resultant URI (`/users/1`).

#### 2. [Updating resources](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating)

Here is where JSON API and I differ. JSON API advocates for *PATCH* requests. I'm not a fan of PATCH (probably because I'm reluctant to send chunks of my data model). Nevertheless, both assume that the resource already exists (step 1).

Look at the example.

**2.1. Request**

```
PATCH /articles/1 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json
```

As for *creation*, the response status code will depend on the state of the resource on the server-side. You will have to decide in every case which one to use.

#### Summing up

Essentially, the resource creation in two steps can be translated into:

- Step 1: Create (POST /users)
- Step 2: Update (PATCH /users/here_your_identifier)

Comment: Hi - I'm using JSON-API. Your answer fails to address my question: what should the second call look like?

Comment: @ProgrammerNewbie Done. Hope it helps. Anyways, JSON API documentation is very well written, everything you need to know about how to proceed is there.